# Counterexamples for L1-convergence not implying L2-convergence and vice versa

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to find counterexamples for the following statements.

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, and let $f$ also be in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^d) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
>
> - $f_n \stackrel{L^1}{\longrightarrow} f$ implies $f_n \stackrel{L^2}{\longrightarrow} f$
> - $f_n \stackrel{L^2}{\longrightarrow} f$ implies $f_n \stackrel{L^1}{\longrightarrow} f$

A counterexample for the first statement would be $f_n:= \sqrt{n}\cdot \chi_{[0,1/n]}$ and $f\equiv 0$.

However, I am having trouble figuring out a counterexample for the second statement. I originally thought it was true but apparently it is not... Any hints for a counterexample would be appreciated. I would also like to know if there are any extra conditions that would make the second statement true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $f_n=n^{-1}\chi_{(0,n)}$: then $\lVert f_n\rVert_2=n^{-1/2}$ and $\lVert f_n\rVert_1=1$.

Comment: I think the $L^2$-norm should be $n^{-1}$, but I see how this works, thanks! Do you know of any extra conditions that would make $L^2$-convergences imply $L^1$-convergence?

Comment: If the measure space is finite, this is ok.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the square root in the $L^2$-norm, ignore my previous comment. Ah ok, I was using Chebychev to attempt to prove that the statement was true, but was only successful when restricted to bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, which coincides with your statement.